Do copyright transfer of papers to publishers affect when the paper enters the public domain since copyright belongs to a corporation and not persons?
Currently, in both the USA and Europe, I understand that works enter the public domain:

70 years after the death of the longest living author
or X years after publication if copyright is held by a corporation, where X is 70 in Europe and 95 in the USA

This means that in general, corporate works enter the public domain much sooner than non-corporate ones.
So does a typical copyright transfer of an academic paper to an academic publisher make such papers enter the public domain X years after publication rather than 70 years after the death of the longest living author?
Or are the copyright transfers so varied that it is not possible to simply answer?
As a concrete example, consider the main Stern-Gerlach experiment published in Germany in 1922: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01326983 Stern died in 1969, Gerlach died in 1979, so if we consider:

death + 70: 2049
publication + 70: 1992, already in public domain

Perhaps the concept of work for hire comes into play here. It does not feel intuitively that papers are work for hire strictly speaking. But it feels unfair that publishers should retain indefinite corporate ownership while still keeping the death + 70 rule to paywall things for even longer.
Related questions:

How long does it take before an academic article can no longer be kept behind a paywall?

Do Research Papers have Public Domain Expiration Date?

Journal allows me to choose whether to transfer copyright – why would I do so? suggests that there are two different types of deal, one in which you transfer copyright and one in which you don't. It would be interesting to understand how popular each one is:

why would authors choose to transfer copyright it not forced to do so by the publisher?
how is an exclusive deal different from copyright transfer?




The question of "work for hire" is often answered in the contract between the author and their employer. For academics, typically the employer waives the copyright and allows the author to retain it, so it ends up not being a work for hire.

@NateEldredge yes, that's what I understand. It just feels unfair that then are in many cases basically forced to waive copyright to a publisher who then gets to keep life + X despite being a corporation.

Copyright law differs and changes. For much of the world, however, note The Berne Convention. Note also that individual countries can differ in part from the convention while still adhering to it.
But for things like academic writings, the copyright begins when the work is "fixed" in some form (not necessarily published). It ends a certain number of years after the death of the "author(s)", not the copyright holder. Transfer of copyright doesn't affect that. If you write something and transfer copyright to, say, Springer, you are still the author.
Works done for hire might be a special case, but you need to explore that, as IANAL. Is the corporation the author or those who work on it? And as this is all civil law, lawyers matter.
Disney tried and almost succeeded in getting perpetual copyright for what it produces. It is a political as well as a legal and financial issue.
And note the exceptions, for such things as anonymous works or unknown author work.
Also note that if copyright transfer extended the term of copyright then a company could in principle transfer copyrights back and forth among its subsidiaries indefinitely, possibly resulting in infinite terms.

Thanks, I imagined that this would be the case unfortunately. Work for hire affects it for sure as it is what characterizes corporate authorship, which is likely does not apply for the broken paper industry unfortunately. "Also note that if copyright transfer extended the term of copyright then a company could in principle transfer copyrights back and forth among its subsidiaries": this wouldn't work because what should count is the publication date which is unchanged.
